# Is it possible to perform an atomic update of event attendees?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have some code that checks the existing attendees, and adds an attendee before calling `patch` with the modified event. This code can be called by multiple callers at the same time. Is there a way to guarantee (e.g., via transaction) that everyone will actually be added, and avoid any race conditions?

Comment: As long as the request executes successfully all the attendees should be added with no issues. Would you mind providing more details about this?

Comment: Client 1 adds attendee A at the same time as Client 2 adds attendee B. I want both attendee A and attendee B to be added, without the clients overwriting each other and just adding one attendee.